# A point whose coordinates are both integers is called a lattice point. How many lattice points lie on the hyperbola $x^2 -y^2 = 2000^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I found [this answer here on AoPS.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2000_AIME_II_Problems/Problem_2) I agree with the answer till it multiplies $49$ by $2$. I think it should be multiplied by $4$ since there are $4$ possible cases:

1) $x+y, x-y$ is positive.

2) $x+y$ is neg and $x-y$ is pos.

3) $x+y$ is pos and $x-y$ is neg.

4) $x+y,x-y$ are neg.

So, I think the answer must be $49 \cdot 4 = 196$.

Consider, the case $x+y=4000$ and $x-y=1000$. There are 4 solutions. $(2500, 1500), (-2500, 1500), (2500, -1500), (-2500, -1500)$.

Am I right? If not, can you highlight my fault and an intuitive understanding to the question?

Comment: $x+y$ and $x-y$ must be of the same sign as their product is positive.
Also, $(-1001, 999)$ is not a solution as $x-y=-2000$, not $2$.

Comment: @user202729 But see the real equation. Squares turn them positive.

Comment: It is $x$ and $y$ that is squared, not $x+y$ and $x-y$.

Comment: @user202729 Those solutions are for $(x,y)$.

Comment: But whatever those solutions are for, it must satisfy original equation. Isn't that what "solution" called?

Comment: @user202729 Corrected it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38339/discussion-between-user202729-and-dhruv).

Comment: In your example, $(-2500,1500)$ and $(2500,-1500)$ come from $x+y=1000, x-y=4000$.  You are double counting, once from a sign inversion and once from interchanging $x-y, x+y$

Answer (score 1):

Take the simpler case $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)=20^2=2^4\cdot 5^2$  We give a factor $2$ to each of $x,y$ then distribute the factors of $2^2 \cdot 5^2$ to $x+y,x-y$.  There are $9$ of them:  $1,2,4,5,10,20,25,50,100$  The case $x-y=8, x+y=50$ gives $x=29, y=21$.  You cannot separately pick the signs of $x+y$ and $x-y$, because they need to be of the same sign.  There are only two cases, not four.

Comment: I graphed your example and you can see that there are 4 points. ![Here.][1] [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/agvcS.jpg   All four of these points lie on the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 20^2$.

Comment: Oh! So I think you mean there's a case when $x_1 = y_2$ and $y_1 = x_2$? Here $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2 ,y_2)$ are solutions to the original equation.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at the case $x>y>0$; the other cases are derived by varying the signs of $x$ and $y$. Write the equation as $$2x=a+\frac{2000^2}a,$$where $a=x-y$. The number of distinct possible values for $2x$ is the number of even factors $\leqslant2000$ of $2000^2=2^85^6$ that have have an even co-factor. These comprise $7\times3=21$ numbers of the form $2^m5^n$ $(m=1,...,7;\,n=0,1,2)$, $4$ of the form $2^m5^3$, and one further factor, namely $1250$: altogether $26$. Considering now the variation of signs gives the total number of $(x,y)$ pairs as $4\times26=104$.